# Expanded textfield strach a lot

Tags: flutter

and at the signup screen I got some problems when I run my app on the device. This happens with the screen : [photo with textfields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxxwQ.png). What I should change to my code to everything to be in place? The app is made with flutter , should I add a height and width to containers? Or should I erase the Expanded and try something else

```
class SignupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignupPageState createState() => _SignupPageState();
}

class _SignupPageState extends State<SignupPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String error = '';
  String _selectedRole = 'Select a User Role';
  String get selectedRole => _selectedRole;

  int selectedValue;
  String selectedString;

//  void setSelectedRole(String role) {
//    _selectedRole = role;
//  }

  bool loading = false;
  final Authentication authentication = Authentication();
  int selectedIndex1 = 0;

  final elements1 = [
    "Customer",
    "Business",
  ];

  List<Widget> _buildItems1() {
    return elements1
        .map((val) => MySelectionItem(
              title: val,
            ))
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
//            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
//            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.blue),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  text: 'Tariffo',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      fontFamily: 'SignPainter',
                      fontSize: 60),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 30.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'enter name' : null,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() => name = val);
                          },
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Enter Name',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Antra',
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                  color: Colors.black)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                                              child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 40.0),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            validator: (val) =>
                                val.isEmpty ? 'Enter Email' : null,
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              setState(() => email = val);
                            },
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Enter email',
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Antra',
                                    fontSize: 12.0,
                                    color: Colors.black)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                                              child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            validator: (val) => val.length < 8
                                ? 'enter password > 8 digits'
                                : null,
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              setState(() => password = val);
                            },
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Enter Password',
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Antra',
                                    fontSize: 12.0,
                                    color: Colors.black)),
                            obscureText: true,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      
                      Expanded(
                                              child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:10.0),
                          child: DirectSelect(
                          
                              itemExtent: 50.0,
                              selectedIndex: selectedIndex1,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
                              child: MySelectionItem(
                                isForList: false,
                                title: elements1[selectedIndex1],
                              ),
                              onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedIndex1 = index;
                                });
                              },
                              items: _buildItems1()),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                                              child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:40.0),
                          child: MaterialButton(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            height: 30,
                            minWidth: 300,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                setState(() => loading = true);

                                dynamic result = await authentication
                                    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password,
                                        name, elements1[selectedIndex1]);
                                if (elements1[selectedIndex1] == 'Business') {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      new MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (_) => BusinessPage()));
                                } else {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      new MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (_) => Homepage()));
                                }
                                if (result == null) {
                                  setState(() => error =
                                      'Sorry,These credentials will not work out');
                                  loading = false;
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              'Sign up',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Antra', color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            _createAccountLabel(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _createAccountLabel() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Do you have an account ?',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Text(
              'Login',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  fontSize: 13,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to reproduce your problem with a simplified version of it. We can't just copy your whole code, especially without your imported files, to test it. Please create a simple view where this issue is reproducible.

Comment: Why did you decide to have every field wrapped with the Expanded Widget?

Comment: Because it wrote before overflow bottom 129 pixels

Comment: I would like to help you, but we need a simplified version of the code, reproducing your issue.

Comment: where you have textFields wrapped in padding remove this top: 30.0

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TJz5BKA I remove expanded and got this , if I remove padding the textfields collide